# How do I change a bulb from my recessed lighting fixture?

Tags: bulb, socket

A light bulb went out in my storage room and to my surprise its socket and peripheral looks quite complex and all bolted into one piece, meaning I couldn't find screws which I can loose to open it.

Anyway it looks like the pictures below.

Can anyone tell me how I can open this thing and change the bulb inside?

Update: I changed the bulb, it is as easy as, changing a bulb. :)

Thanks to all answers and comments, you guys are awesome!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try grabbing the trim ring underneath the edges and pulling straight down. They usually have a springy bracket that holds them in place. Once down, the bulb will be exposed.

Answer (score 16):

Here is what the process of pulling the cover down will look like. The bulb is inside. If you can't get your fingers around it to unscrew it and need to use the suction cup, you can squeeze the spring clips and remove the entire trim ring assembly. Pay attention to how it came out, you'll need to reverse that process to get it back in.
[image]

Comment: Rather than changing the bulb, look for an "LED retrofit" that replaces both the bulb and the cover. These are very easy to install and look nicer than a standalone bulb.

Comment: @DavidPhillips in this case because the trim has an integrated lens an LED retrofit would look pretty much the same. It might be cheaper to just screw in an LED bulb.

Comment: Be careful with the lens! In some fixtures it's glass, and held in place with nothing but gravity. Ask me how I know...

Answer (score 7):

On many types of fixtures... You just unscrew the bulb!

On those fixtures there is a small margin between the bezel and the flat lensed/Fresnel'd surface. That flat surface **is the bulb**.

See, it looks like this...

[image]

So how do you grab a flat flush bulb?  Suction cup.

Comment: Taking 30 seconds to pull down the trim ring will expose the edge of the bulb, so you can grab the bulb with your fingers and not need a suction cup.

Comment: While this type of bulb is used in some recessed cans, from the photo the actual bulb doesn't appear to be visible. Its a lens on the trim which is visible.

Comment: @AndyB Assuming that type of trim drops right down like that.  It doesn't always, and you can gouge up your drop ceiling panel by trying.